# how convert string to path in opemnmt-py

Tags: python, pytorch, opennmt

I use opennmt-py for MT and in the code any time I want to set a path I have to write all directory and it's not good looking when I have long directory. is there any way to set a string as the main directory and just add the file name to the end.
I use google colab to train the model 
**The code is like:**

```
!onmt_preprocess  \\
-train_src //content//drive//My\ Drive//Colab\ Notebooks//NLP//spring99//CA6//Corpora//En2Fa-Translation//train.en \\
-train_tgt //content//drive//My\ Drive//Colab\ Notebooks//NLP//spring99//CA6//Corpora//En2Fa-Translation//train.fa \\
-valid_src //content//drive//My\ Drive//Colab\ Notebooks//NLP//spring99//CA6//Corpora//En2Fa-Translation//dev.en \\
-valid_tgt  //content//drive//My\ Drive//Colab\ Notebooks//NLP//spring99//CA6//Corpora//En2Fa-Translation//dev.fa \\
-save_data //content//drive//My\ Drive//Colab\ Notebooks//NLP//spring99//CA6//Corpora//En2Fa-Translation//demo//
```

**and the code I want to be like:**

```
path ='//content//dri`ve//My\ Drive//Colab\ Notebooks//NLP//spring99//CA6//Corpora//En2Fa-Translation//'

!onmt_preprocess  \\
-train_src path+'train.en' \\
-train_tgt path+'train.fa' \\
-valid_src path+'dev.en' \\
-valid_tgt  path++'dev.fa' \\
-save_data path+'demo//'
```

or maybe just can write all path in a variable and use it like:

```
path_train ='//content//dri`ve//My\ Drive//Colab\ Notebooks//NLP//spring99//CA6//Corpora//En2Fa-Translation//'

!onmt_preprocess  \\
-train_src path_train \\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a mere concatenation:

```
path='//content//drive//My\ Drive//Colab\ Notebooks//NLP//spring99//CA6//Corpora//En2Fa-Translation//'
!onmt_preprocess  \\
  -train_src $path'train.en' \\
  -train_tgt $path'train.fa' \\
  -valid_src $path'dev.en' \\
  -valid_tgt $path'dev.fa' \\
  -save_data $path'demo//'
```

Notes:

- The variable `path` must be followed with `=`, not a space. There must be no spaces around `=`. The `path = 'text'` is wrong, `path ='text'` is wrong, `path= 'text'` is also wrong.
- When you use a variable, prepend it with `$`: `!echo $path'train.en'` will print `//content//drive//My Drive//Colab Notebooks//NLP//spring99//CA6//Corpora//En2Fa-Translation//train.en`
- Concatenation means just glueing string literals to variables no need using `+`, `&`, etc.

Comment: Does this use a shell or is it just the same syntax? It certainly isn't Python, so that tag might need to be removed from the OP.

Comment: @Graipher That is google colab way of executing bash commands.